# Linux Kernel Firewire Feature: Use Unclear

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, firewire

In the Linux kernel, there is a setting "FireWire SBP-2 fabric module". I do not understand the documentation:

> Say Y or M here to enable SCSI target functionality over FireWire. This enables you to expose SCSI devices to other nodes on the FireWire bus, for example hard disks.

What is the use of this feature? That is, what is it for? Why would someone need to enable this driver?

Comment: Downvoting this because a simple Google search for 'linux scsi over firewire' yields pages like this one [1] where it's all explained. [1] http://linux-iscsi.org/wiki/Target

Comment: @schaiba If you're not familiar with enterprise storage terminology, that page is pretty opaque. This isn't Serverfault, everyone isn't assumed to be a professional sysadmin.

Comment: True, and I don't want to be an a**. But some basic research is expected, in my opinion. That page was given as an example.

Comment: @schaiba I did a quick search, and most of them seem to be full of storage jargon. E.g., http://lwn.net/Articles/491633/ is too.

Comment: @derobert, thanks for your comments. For it to be so "simple", I find it odd that schaiba never answered the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put: it lets the computer pretend to be a disk drive as far as the computer on the other end of the cable is concerned.